# Tag burnination request: [coding-style]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just became aware that the [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) tag is still alive on Stack Overflow, and it seems like the whole tag is inviting questions that are primarily opinion-based. The tag's history goes all the way back to 2008, so I think it's a remnant of our free-spirited, anything-goes-as-long-as-it's-programming-related past (I've even answered several of these questions myself).

Before we scorch this patch of earth, I want to ask the community, is there anything we can salvage from this tag? Is there some subset of these questions that we can define in the tag wiki that would be acceptable, or is the tag just too inviting of off-topic navel gazing?

Comment: Wow, finally a burninate-request from the lizard himself. ;-) BTW: Did you also take a look at [tag:conventions]?

Comment: @Deduplicator Even I can't breathe enough fire to take out 6000+ questions by myself. ;) No, I didn't see the conventions tag. That looks like pretty much the same thing on a slightly smaller scale. Definitely worth looking at.

Comment: It's not the tag that is causing questions that are primarily opinion-based, it's the askers.  How do we feel about the on topic-ness of coding style questions?  The highest-voted ones seem OK to me.

Comment: There's also the deal with people using [coding-style] to mean [style]... just because of the substring.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is there anything about them we can define in the wiki? I see a few that are good, but many are... meh. I like "When to use double vs. single quotes?" for example, because it can change the way code behaves. I have the sense that the answer to 9 out of 10 of these questions is "It doesn't matter. Follow the style of the project you're working in."

Comment: Creating such an article for the wiki might be a better use of our time than trying to remove six thousand tags one at a time.

Comment: @BoltClock You're right, that complicates this mess. The 'style' tag is ambiguous to begin with, and there are also people using both tags to ask about enforcing style rules in IDEs (which I think is totally on-topic).

Comment: "ask about enforcing style rules in IDEs" those should be tagged with the $IDE tag, no? or we are going to have the plethora of [coding-style] + [idle]; [coding-style] + [eclipse]; [coding-style] + [emacs]; [coding-style] + [X]; etc.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, those definitely need the IDE tag. I don't think it hurts to leave the [coding-style] tag on them, unless there's a better tag specifically for that kind of question. The main point in my earlier comment is that those questions should stay open, unlike most questions in the [coding-style] tag.

Comment: Can we blacklist this thing?

Answer (score 25):

It's my opinion that the current wiki for [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) covers only opinionated topics. A "generic tag" that covers generally-accepted principles is hardly objective; how many spaces you indent, what you should name you functions/variables, whether you use camelCase or snake_case, etc. are all matters of opinion.

My suggestion: Update the tag wiki to `DO NOT USE` and burninate.

Update: It's now been 10 days with no objection to this, I'll go ahead and start.

I've updated the tag wiki to include a "DO NOT USE" phrase, and have started the burnination.

- Starting numbers in Jan 2016 are ~5770 questions that have the tag and are not closed.
- As of March 2018 the number of unclosed questions with this tag is: 6,061, or 85% of the questions in the tag.

Comment: Someone decided in Jan 2018 that this is a fantastic tag, but solely for Java, so they edited the excerpt to be about that and no longer about "DO NOT USE". Also the count of open questions in March 2018 is 6060

Comment: @Adriaan I have re-added the warning to the wiki and excerpt. We will hopefully cover this soon thanks to the Trogdor chatroom efforts coordinated by Jon and co.

Comment: TylerH, I respectfully but rather strongly disagree with your answer. Whether "behaviour" should be spelled "behavior" is clearly opinionated. Agreed?
But the vast majority would not question that the first spelling is known as _British English_ and the second _American English_. There is no room for opinions on that.
Just as anyone using a natural language should be concerned with bad grammar and spelling mistakes, so should we programmers be concerned with bad coding style.
(to be continued)

Comment: (continued)
_Should I use camelCase or snake case?_ is clearly opinionated. But _Does [JavaScript Standard Style](https://standardjs.com/rules.html) prescribe camelCase or snake case?_
is clearly ***not*** opinionated. Take the question _Where do I find the **JavaScript Standard Style (guide)**?_ as an example. Clearly ***not*** opinionated - agreed?
So what tag do you suggest for this and similar highly on-topic questions if you have burninated (or deprecated) all tags related to coding conventions?

Comment: @Henke No, behaviour should be spelled behaviour if you use British English. It should be spelled behavior if you use American English. That's not a matter of opinion. Regarding style guides, use a tag for that specific style guide. Questions in Python, for example, trying to comply with PEP-8 (a style guide) are OK because they're asking how to comply with an objective metric: what PEP-8 says; questions asking how to style Python code in general or whether they *should* comply with PEP-8 are opinion-based and thus off-topic.

Comment: @Henke In the same vein, if there is some entity called "the JavaScript Standard Style" and it lays out rules, then questions on how to comply with those rules are fine, and no different from questions asking "does this code syntax comply with the <official language specification>". Such questions should use a [tag:js-standard-style] tag or something similar.

Comment: @Henke Regarduing "burninated (or deprecated all tags related to coding conventions)", this Q&A and any related activity are only focused on the tag [tag:coding-style], not "all tags related to coding conventions".

Answer (score -8):

Personally I believe nothing should be done about the tag and the "DO NOT USE" notice should be removed.

This is not because questions purely asking about stylistic preference are on-topic, but because tagging is a separate problem.

#### [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) is useful for cataloging

Let's look at a few high-quality questions which are tagged [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style):

- [Should you use const in function parameters, and why does it not affect the function signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/should-you-use-const-in-function-parameters-and-why-does-it-not-affect-the-func)
  This question is asking about coding style and should be appropriately tagged, but it also asks about language semantics which arguably is on-topic overall. It is well-received with 524 upvotes. Note that I have added [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) myself to this question because it obviously asks about coding style, and such tagging is correct for cataloging until burnination (if ever). This was what motivated me to post this answer.
- [Why is it recommended to have empty line in the end of a source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2287967/5740428)
  This question asks about something which looks like stylistic preference, however, there are very practical reasons such as compatibility with older tools. The question is and should be tagged [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style), however, the answers are not opinion-based.
- [80-characters / right margin line in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25900954/5740428)
  This question is not asking about stylistic preference, but rather about how to get a specific editor to assist in enforcing the user's stylistic preference. This is obviously not opinion-based. [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) is still appropriate.

A substantial amount of questions fall into these patterns of asking about stylistic preference, but the answers aren't opinion-based regardless, or the question is about assistance with a coding style. Removing the [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) tag from these questions or burninating it entirely would merely hurt cataloging.

In conclusion, there is substantial evidence that [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) is useful for cataloging. Merely looking at the list of questions with this tag makes it obvious that the tag is meaningful.

#### [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) encouraging opinion-based questions is conjecture

It can be argued that the mere existence of [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) encourages opinion-based answers.
However, no substantial evidence to support this claim has been brought forth. It would need to be shown that the creation of opinion-based answers would have been prevented if the tag didn't exist.

It is plausible that without [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style), opinon-based questions would have been asked, and simply would be missing the tag.
This would be a worse outcome overall, since we would have the same opinon-based questions, but they would be more difficult to find. Only harm is done.

#### Conclusion

There is substantial evidence that [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) is useful for cataloging, and no substantial evidence that the removal of the tag is beneficial to the website.

Many questions tagged with [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) are off-topic, but blaming the tag is conjecture, and it conflates correlation with causation.

**Therefore, the DO NOT USE notice and attempt to burninate the tag is unreasonable.**

Comment: The current tag's wiki recommends to ask "objective" questions about coding style on Software Engineering SE. At least, this recommendation has some reasons, but your answer doesn't discuss it when suggesting to allow coding style questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Note that I have added `coding-style` myself to this question because it obviously asks about coding style, and such tagging is correct for cataloging until burnination (if ever)."  - Some other user disagreed with you and [have removed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/117293/5) both the tag and coding style aspects from the post. Not that I find that last edit to be correct: it invalidates at least several existing answers. But I also don't find useful to add tags which are currently under discussion.

Answer (score -10):

Ok. Protest.

I realize that coding-style questions get downvoted. I realize that there might be people out there who believe that this is "opinionated" or "bad" or otherwise "not ok".

I disagree.

As an educator I have always taken and defended the position that **no** question is a bad question. However, there are plenty of bad answers. The tag system is a very good approach to squelch the volume on topics one is not interested. However, there may be people who are seriously interested in discussions on coding-style and this site would be the generic place to do so. Burninating, banning or otherwise downvoting questions on coding-style, to me, truly is a **socially abusive behavior** of those who believe to know towards those who want to learn because it deprives those who want to learn from their learning and discussing opportunities.

Thank you for listening. Now you can start to hit back :-)

Comment: Not unexpected that I get downvoted. Such a 'bad' question could be a starting point for explaining why it is bad - or for simply ignoring it. The tag system makes ignoring easy. What is done here is essentially preventing questions from being asked. I consider this socially abusive. Sorry for that.

Comment: `As an educator I have always taken and defended the position that no question is a bad question.` That means nothing.  What we care is whether the question is a good fit for this community. "How are the wife and the kids?" Not a "bad" question. Should we allow it on Stackoverflow? No! Why? Because it's offtopic. Why is it offtopic? Because we decided that this community should only have questions that are about "programming". If you can reword your answer to say, why this tag is needed or why this is on-topic, quoting relevant rules of the community,defending your position, that'll be better.

Comment: Also see [tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/coding-style/info). It cites where these questions maybe ontopic.

Comment: @TheMaster: Thank you for the first constructive comment in this discussion, as hinting to ontopic places. In my perception all this is not so much about "offtopic" but on" power" and on questioning power structures of social networks. It's the way we humans function, we don't want to see our belief systems challenged and we usually punish those who do. Whatever.

Comment: While I agree that  there is that part of the human behavior, you have to consider whether that's a factor(or if it is, the only factor) at play here. Or whether we have community rules for a reason and enforce it for a reason other than being drunk on power.