# Alternatives to [coding-style] and similar tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I understand that these tags would attract opinionated discussions. However I am convinced that coding-style is an important topic with many aspects that can be discussed objectively. I mean, it's not only about the number of columns to use for indentation.

So are there any alternative tags for coding style and coding convention related topics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking here. It seems to me that you want to ask a question that should be tagged [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style), but you're worried that the tag's presence will attract negative attention, so you're hoping to sneak it in under the radar with some other tag? Sorry, I can't support that.

There would be no point in having alternate tags that cover the same ground. It would just make it harder to find questions.

If you think you have a reasonable, objective, answerable question about coding style, tag it appropriately and see how it fares. I agree that there are such questions, they are just rare.

If you have a question in mind that you *think* is good, but you are unsure how to ask it in the best way, then you should ask a Meta question about that. Include the proposed text of your question and ask for help on composing it in a suitable manner. You'll either be told "aww hell no" or "write it this-a-way instead."

Comment: Maybe I was misunderstanding the following description of the tag: "DO NOT USE! This tag refers to an entirely opinionated subject and is therefore no longer on-topic.". I interpreted this as the whole tag is deprecated and I am not suposed to post there.

Comment: Hmm yeah, the "aww hell no" people have already begun to assemble. Consider contributing your opinion to the contrary [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278455/tag-burnination-request-coding-style). Again, the problem is not the *tag*, but the types of questions that it invites.