# The tag "coding-style" has a DO-NOT-USE hint, but how should we tag questions about style guide tools?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) tag has a **DO-NOT-USE** hint, but how should one tag a question about style guide or style enforcement tools?

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39121577/3719459) asks about the [McCabe complexity test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) and *Landscape.io* and how to disable such a rule for some methods. The only valid tag seems to be [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). That doesn't look satisfying.

**Edit:**
New tag [landscape.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/landscape.io) is online and has a first wiki text. I also contacted the tool author, to update a better wiki text.

Comment: Well, you always (understand almost always) need to select a language's tag aniway if you want to have answers, because there are more people that will follow `python` tag that all the other ones that can be used along with it.

Comment: I removed the tag from your question. Don't use it.

Comment: There is an open burninate-request for that tag: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278455/tag-burnination-request-coding-style

Comment: Maybe we can add some documentation on how to not use it and then link to it. Let's see how much rep we can get.

Comment: Huh? There are already 2 persons committed. That was fast!

Comment: Isn't style enforcement just one of the functions performed by source-analysis / [tag:static-analysis] tools?  Aren't the existing tags for those good enough?  [tag:code-analysis] [tag:static-code-analysis]

Comment: Such analyzers have deep code knowledge, so they can do style reports and enforcements, too. But that's not the primary goal of such tools.

Answer (score 22):

Questions about style enforcement tools should use a tag specific to the tool. You can create a tag if it doesn't exist yet. (See [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/247702))
If a specific tag is not applicable, it's most likely a question asking to recommend a tool, which is off-topic.

If a question is asking for what the official style guide says on a subject, e.g. *what does the official style guide say about variable casing*, it's off-topic for requesting to locate an external resource. The asker should find the guide and the applicable section themself. (Questions asking how to *interpret* it are another matter, but I've never run into such a problem myself. I've always found official style guides to be very explicit.)

If a question is polling for commonly used styles, it's off-topic for being primarily opinion based.

Comment: I was not sure if I should create a tag for Landscape.io (should it be named with "dot io"? It's a addon service for GitHub and quite many projects use it to check their python repositories. (landscape is reserved for a view orientation...

Comment: @Paebbels creating a tag for that is fine. I'm not sure on the format, but I think *landscape.io* is fine. There's a meta post somewhere that details this. Also take a look at [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944/247702)

Comment: *"If a question is about an official style guide, it's off-topic for requesting to locate an external resource."* - huh? I have no idea what you're trying to say here. Asking how to interpret a style guide - just like asking how to interpret a  spec - is potentially a perfectly good, on-topic question. And whatever its merits, such a question is *definitely* not a resource request. I'm not sure what sort of questions "about" a style guide you're envisaging for which what you're saying would apply.

Comment: @MarkAmery How about [c++ - Links to official style guides](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434213/links-to-official-style-guides)?

Comment: I wouldn't call that a question about *an* official style guide, @DavidMoles, so I presume it's not what Stijn is talking about. Perhaps it's just unclear wording on his part, though - I'm unsure.

Comment: @MarkAmery What if the title (rephrasing slightly from the question text) was “Does anyone have an official C++ style guide?” — I'm not saying this is what Stijn necessarily meant, but it's certainly what I took him to mean before I saw your comment.

Comment: "If a question is about an official style guide, it's off-topic for requesting to locate an external resource." This is poorly phrased. If the question is asking us to provide one, you're correct. If someone is asking about the *interpretation* of one, that's not asking for an external resource. It might still be off-topic (I'm honestly not sure. That doesn't sound too different from interpreting the C standard to me.), but it doesn't fit into what you've said here. Could you rephrase, please?

Comment: @MarkAmery and others: I've rephrased the sentence. I honestly haven't thought about questions asking how to interpret an official style guide because I've never run into such a problem myself. I've always found official style guides to be very explicit.

Comment: "If a question is polling for commonly used styles" too broad can also fit.

Comment: Asking for an interpretation of a style-guide would be "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: @MarkR "Interpretation" might be a deceptive word. I can imagine plenty of questions about what a style guide is saying where the answer could be something like *"The word you're confused about is defined in the glossary as ..."* or *"This situation is clarified in appendix A where it says ..."* or even *"The guide doesn't say anything about this particular scenario. (Other guides say ...)"*.

Answer (score -6):

For questions about **formatting** source code, the tag [code-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-formatting) is available.

Comment: Looks like a good tag to put up for burnination, I think....

Comment: @Makoto Why? What's wrong with asking about code formatting?

Comment: You're asking about a *tool* that does the code formatting, not specifically formatting code yourself.  As in, an answer that applies to code formatting for VSCode would probably be set up differently in IntelliJ or Vim or Emacs or Notepad++.  But this is a cursory look at this; I'd need to put together a post about this later if I were bothered to do so.

Comment: @Makoto Huh? Who said it's specific to formatting tools (or IDEs or w/e)?

Comment: Non-tool-specific questions about formatting source code are going to be either "how do I get the code to be formatted properly?" (off topic - either NMF or looking for a tool); "how do I write code to manipulate other code, for the purpose of formatting it?" (either NMF or else it doesn't actually matter that the input is source code) or "what formatting should the code have?" (opinion based). In every case, I see no way that a tag like this adds value.

Comment: @Karl OK, I see what you mean. And for questions about style guides, I suppose they should be tagged with the style guide.

Comment: Sure, but there are very few questions that meet standards there. After all, the style guide exists, and by virtue of existing it is written down and documented. We aren't in the business of finding it for people, and interpreting it is likely subjective.