# Burninate or clean up the [coding-style] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, clean-up

I recently encountered the [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) tag, which attracts a large number of subjective and argumentative questions. Its tag description is:

> DO NOT USE! This tag refers to an entirely opinionated subject and is therefore no longer on-topic. Questions about coding style and conventions.

While this tag is technically unambiguous, identifies a programming topic, and adds context information, it's on a topic that's typically heavily opinion-based. The vast majority of questions that this tag would apply to shouldn't be asked here.

At a minimum, this tag needs significant cleanup. In my opinion, we should just remove it entirely.

Comment: I had understood that *generally* tag descriptions starting with "DO NOT USE" occur because there was a burnination in progress... ?

Comment: Won't dupehammer, but this has been posted before: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278455/tag-burnination-request-coding-style Unfortunately at ~8000 uses, it would require a huge effort to clean-up/destroy.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel many uses of that pre-date the current burnination process and in general are just used by hopeful editors to dissuade usage of blatantly off-topic tags. It was especially common for people to just edit that into wiki excerpts circa 2014-2017.

Comment: Count this as a meh from me. It's off topic when asking about "which coding style is best". It's on topic if it's about configuring a prettifier/IDE/linter/etc to aid or enforce a specific coding style afaik

Comment: While we're at it, a lot of [code-* and/or coding-*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-*+or+coding-*) tags seem to be misused. I once tried to tackle [code-cleanup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383165/its-time-for-code-cleanup) and [code-translation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408112/clean-up-code-translation), but it was not deemed a big enough issue at the time of asking.

Comment: The fact that "DO NOT USE!" is in the tag description helps users to **not** post their question - it gives the user a hint that the question may be off topic. So this tag with this description is useful to keep.

Comment: @TimurShtatland I disagree. People [ignore tag usage guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346150/how-should-we-deal-with-people-misusing-the-visual-studio-and-android-studio) all the time, and the mere existence of such a tag is a broken window that suggests to people that that type of question is ok here.

Comment: Related: [The tag "coding-style" has a DO-NOT-USE hint, but how should we tag questions about style guide tools?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333076/the-tag-coding-style-has-a-do-not-use-hint-but-how-should-we-tag-questions-ab)

Comment: @ErikA Is [tag:coding-style] relevant for a prettifier/linter? Wouldn't one just be fine/better off tagging the prettifier/linter and language? See the above link

Comment: @TylerH Not really, it can add a tiny bit of context (specifically for linters, since they tend to do other things as well, e.g. static code analysis). Not a great tag, but not off topic and not really meeting the burnination criteria unless you stretch them a bit. I'd rather see it gone than stay, but we have lots of worse tags in the queue.

Comment: There is already a burnination request about this tag. Please keep all discussion to a single post. There are recent additions to the discussion there.